# "Alignment grid" suddenly showed up on my desktop

Tags: macos

I am on OS X 10.9   Yesterday, an "alignment grid" mysteriously showed up on my desktop.  How do I get rid of it?

[image: A photo of a desktop with alignment grid (on 10.11.4) as the grid doesn't appear on screenshots]

The grid lines don't show up when I do a proper, OS X screenshot. So I've taken a picture of my physical monitor, an Asus monitor, to show the problem.

Comment: A screenshot would be useful

Comment: I love these 'screenshots'! (next time try `command alt shift 3` ;)

Comment: @CousinCocaine maybe it's from the Monitor, so screenshot won't capture it?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek, indeed, and because the lines pass over the menubar this might indeed be the case.

Comment: @Rogier, can you capture a screenshot using `Command` `Shift` `Option` `3` and post it as well? If the lines are not present on that screenshot, the lines are probably not coming from your OS, but from the monitors software itself.

Comment: @Rogier you should post the answer in the answer section below. Don't edit the question and post it in the question body. You're quite correct: the problem is with the physical monitor, that's why it doesn't show up when you use the OS to take a screen shot.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, the problem is with the monitor (Asus in my case), not OS X. You should be able to reset this - i.e. make the grid disappear - via the monitor's menu 'System Setup'.

Comment: worked for me too! +1

Answer (score 1):

S/A button on my Asus monitor turned mine off

Comment: this one fixed mine too, thank you very much! [+1]